# Why does a magnet in a non-uniform magnetic field experience a force?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Magnets in a non-uniform magnetic field, like the one emerging from one end of a solenoid, will move. Why does this happen, and how do we "predict" which direction the magnet will move in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The north pole of magnet feels a force in the direction of the magnetic field while The south pole feels a force in the opposite direction from the magnetic field. If the magnetic field is uniform and the magnet dipoles are identical (apart from one being north pole and the other south pole) this two forces cancels out.

Because each dipole is effected by the magnetic that exist in its positions, **if the magnetic field is non-uniform then the forces on the north pole and on the south pole won't be equal and the magnet will experience a total force different from 0**.

In order to predict in which direction the magnet will move (i.e. assuming that the magnet start at rest then this direction will be the same as the direction of the total force that the magnet experience) you need to **calculate the two forces that acting on the two poles, and then calculate the direction of the total force**.
Note that in the general case the magnet will also spin around itself because of a the total [torque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torque) that the magnet experience. If you want also to predict in each direction it will rotate, you need to calculate the total torque.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! :)